# Which one os better for Ns2 and sumo installation Cygwin or ubuntu?

Tags: ns2, sumo

which one is preferable for installation and execution's of NS2 and SUMO .Cygwin or ubuntu?

Comment: I cannot speak for ns2 but for sumo it is definitely ubuntu

Comment: Suggest : Install both .... try out both. ...... Please be aware that ns2 requires an old compiler ... and that some old simulations require an old Ubuntu version : Ubuntu 16.04 or older. ( Sumo is updated, can use a new OS. ( ns2 is 20 years old.)) https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dbrFE8CDMNbE5Kmq4duZl6bUTP7PXdVps9AGvzVi0gM/edit?usp=sharing